# read hive table in a python script within a shell oozie action

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hive, oozie-workflow

I have the following python script shell_csv.sh running in an oozie shell action:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import csv
import sys
import os
import subprocess 


csv.field_size_limit(300000)


with open(r'csv_1.csv', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
with open(r'csv_2.csv', "w") as csvfile_write:
    my_writer= csv.writer(csvfile_write, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for values in my_reader:
        result=[]
        result.append(values)
        my_writer.writerow(result[0])
output, erreur = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-put", "csv_2.csv", "/user/files/csv_2.csv"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

It works perfectly with the "csv_1" file, but now instead of reading the "csv_1" file, I need to read directly from the hive table from which I exported the "csv_1" file.
The workflow is running in a Hadoop server and the hive table is stored in an HDF directory.

Does anyone know how to do this?

PS: do not pay attention to the content of the python script, It just a dummy example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Hive query, Oozie can do that directly with a SQL file.

If you want to interact with Hive tables from Python, look at `pyhive` or `impyla` libraries.

Otherwise, go full `pyspark`, which itself can read/write CSV to/from HDFS along with perform `spark-sql` functions without needing `subprocess` or Hive installation

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you please give more details abouthow to use pyspark in oozie action to do what I'm triying to do ? I've never used Pyspark and i don't know where to begin

Comment: Well, the official Spark documentation can get you started with that. I'm not sure about Pyspark with Oozie, but the docs for that are 
 at https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html